# Save UI and data in android

Tags: android

[image]I am working on a messenger type application,when a user click on a user from chat window I show a blank Layout with a send button and EditText at bottom,now when user type text in Edit Field and click on send I create a dynamic Layout holding some dynamically created other UI component like Label and ImageView etc.now I want to save this UI state when user press back button or home button.I know there is a method for activity like SaveInstance etc it save only data object but here I want to save GUI with data for all chat windows,anyone can guide how I can handle this ?I will be very thankful for guidance. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

You should be storing your data in some place (in memory, like in a static array somewhere, or in sql if you need to keep it across sessions), and displaying a listView with an adapter on this data. then, when adding data, you only need to notify your adapter to refresh the view.

Comment: thanks dear for your detailed ans you are quite right,but on my side chat GUI have some check-box imageViews etc,as ListView takes Array of data and show it but how can I manage ImageViews and state of check-boxes etc(for chat instance messages some are ticked some not) .

Comment: you must be aware that your application can be terminated at any time for memory or whatever reason the system finds fit. Therefore, you probably should consider a stateless system, in which you keep everything in DB as long as you need it. The user checks a box? save it somewhere.

Comment: I attach an image of chat message.Title is the name person,test is the chat message text.there is also a dot on right side that changes its color depending on user's different actions,its ok I can save a flag when I save my data.you are right application can be terminated at any time for memory and its better to save chat in DB,but now on each chat message from both sides there I need to run an insert DB quires that will load on application ?

Comment: to save the each text message in database from both sides it will slow the application ? as both user do messaging quickly and there is always need to run an insert DB query that can slow the application right ?

Comment: if by "quickly" you suggest that a user is able to send several dozens of messages per second, then yes. If they are human, however, you should not have any problem as long as you keep the database open between 2 inserts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3234/discussion-between-aftab-and-njzk2)